# Need to expire parent record if all child records are expired- SQL

Tags: oracle

I have a table JOB_DISPPLAY as under:

```
JOB_STS    JOB NAME    FREQUENCY    CHILD ID   START       END_DATE
 R         JOB001       Daily      
 E         JOB001                    CH001    01-01-2012  12-15-2016
 R         JOB001                    CH002    06-12-2016  01-01-2049

 F         JOB002       Montly       
 E         JOB002                    CH003    06-12-2014  01-01-2016
 E         JOB002                    CH004    03-10-2015  01-01-2016

 R         JOB003       Montly       
 F         JOB003                    CH006    06-12-2014  01-01-2018
 F         JOB003                    CH007    03-10-2015  01-01-2018
```

Here JOB001 is parent and it has 2 childs- CH001 and CH002. Similarly JOB002 is parent and has 2 child CH003 and CH004. Job STatus R=Running, F=Finished and E=Expired

Now i want to update the table for parent record sts such that if ALL child have column end_date in past compared to today i.e if the child records are expired (job_sts =E) then parent record should also expire.

Hence my end result should be with JOB002 whole set expired like:

```
JOB_STS    JOB NAME    FREQUENCY    CHILD ID   START       END_DATE
 R         JOB001       Daily      
 E         JOB001                    CH001    01-01-2012  12-15-2016
 R         JOB001                    CH002    06-12-2016  01-01-2049

 E         JOB002       Montly       
 E                                   CH003    06-12-2014  01-01-2016
 E                                   CH004    03-10-2015  01-01-2016

 R         JOB003       Montly       
 F                                   CH006    06-12-2014  01-01-2018
 F                                   CH007    03-10-2015  01-01-2018
```

How can i achieve this?

Thanks!

Comment: How do you know whose child is `CH003` or `CH007` ? There are only status, chid-id and dates in these records, all remaining columns are null.

Comment: Updated table to have that information, missed that.